# Flink Streaming: window never finalised

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I use a `TumblingWindow` with `EventTime`. Here is a simplified version of my program:

```java
final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic( TimeCharacteristic.EventTime );


DataStream<String> inputStream = env.addSource( 
    new FlinkKafkaConsumer09<>( kafkaInput, new SimpleStringSchema(), prop ) );

SingleOutputStreamOperator<Measure> measureStream = inputStream
    .flatMap( new StringToFloatMeasureFlatMapper() )
    .returns( Measure.class )
    .keyBy( "objectId" )
    // extract event data from measure object
    .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks( new BoundedLatenessMeasureMarker() );


SingleOutputStreamOperator<MeanMinMaxStdAccumulator> stdResults = 
   stdMean.keyBy( "objectId" )
    .timeWindow( Time.minutes(15) )
    .sum("floatValue");

stdResults.print();

env.execute();
```

I extract the timestamps and create the watermarks using the following class:

```java
public class BoundedLatenessMeasureMarker implements AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks<Measure>{

    private final long maxOutOfOrderness = 4000;
    private long currentMaxTimestamp;

    @Override
    public long extractTimestamp(Measure measure, long previousElementTimestamp) {
        long time = measure.timestamp.getTime();
        currentMaxTimestamp = Math.max(time, currentMaxTimestamp);
        return time;
    }

    @Override
    public Watermark getCurrentWatermark() {
        // return the watermark as current highest timestamp minus the out-of-orderness bound
        Watermark watermark = new Watermark( currentMaxTimestamp - maxOutOfOrderness );
        return watermark;
    }
}
```

My problem is: when I run this against real data (i.e. using a kafka topic getting input from about 2000 sensors generating measures every few seconds) it works well, *but when I try to reproduce it on a test topic, the windows never close*.

Here is a sample of my test data:

```
kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic input-test --from-beginning
{"objectId":2,"unitSymbol":"V","timestamp":"2017-01-09T16:57:18","value":"1.0","type":"float","floatValue":0.0}
{"objectId":2,"unitSymbol":"V","timestamp":"2017-01-09T16:58:38","value":"1.0","type":"float","floatValue":0.0}
{"objectId":2,"unitSymbol":"V","timestamp":"2017-01-09T17:07:49","value":"1.0","type":"float","floatValue":0.0}
{"objectId":2,"unitSymbol":"V","timestamp":"2017-01-09T18:37:59","value":"1.0","type":"float","floatValue":0.0}
{"objectId":2,"unitSymbol":"V","timestamp":"2017-01-09T19:18:19","value":"1.0","type":"float","floatValue":0.0}
{"objectId":2,"unitSymbol":"V","timestamp":"2017-01-09T19:20:16","value":"1.0","type":"float","floatValue":0.0}
```

As you can see, the timestamps are clearly ordered in time and cover more than one window of 15 minutes. By adding some println, I could also determine that the watermarks are updating and the fold (in this case the sum) is also done. But windows don't finalize, so the `stdResults.print()` never outputs anything.

Anybody has a hint on what going on here ?

UPDATE: I tried switching from the periodic timestamp to the `AscendingTimestampExtractor`, same problem.

UPDATE: I also checked the kafka topics, they have the exact same configuration.

Comment: How many partitions does your "input-test" topic have? If more than one messages may not be ordered as you think.

Comment: I have only one partition. Even if there is some out-of-order data, shouldn't some windows close anyway after a while ? Also, in the `AscendingTimestampExtractor`, an error message is normally printed if a timestamp is wrong (i.e. late), which does not happen.